# The Redirection plugin for Wordpress isn't working

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I want to redirect all the links in my old wordpress.com to my new .com site, but I keep getting a fail message from Redirection.

I've attached two screenshots to show how I'm trying to create the Redirect and then the fail message. Rather, the photos are showing up as embed links. I've cleared my cache, so I know that's not the issue.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. Please delete your question here and re-ask it there.

Comment: It think this plugin is not meant to redirect different domains, the best case scenario will be try to re-direct from your DNS